# document.createDocumentFragment() seems to get emptied after being appended?

Tags: javascript, dom

If you create a DocumentFragment using `document.createDocumentFragment()`, append children to it, then append the buffer to something, all the children of the buffer seem to disappear. Example:

```
var buffer = document.createDocumentFragment() ;

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = i;
    buffer.appendChild(div);
}

console.log( 'buffer: ' , buffer );

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(buffer);

console.log( 'buffer now: ' , buffer );
```

Here, in the first console.log, the buffer's childNodes has 10 children, in the second, childNodes has 0.

Is there a way to retain the childnodes somewhere and not have them reset, in order to cache the buffer and not have to append children to it each time?

Comment: I hope the example is not production code, right? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just described the nature of a `DocumentFragment`. If you want to reuse the same contents, you could clone the fragment before appending it to the document each time:

```
var bufferCopy = buffer.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(bufferCopy);
```

Comment: I don't think it will offer much performance benefit though, will it? If you have 10-100 children to append to the buffer?

Comment: Option 1: Loop through 10-100 divs and append them to a buffer, then append the buffer to dom whenever user clicks a button, or Option 2: Clone the buffer and store it the first time, and future times just append the cloned/cached buffer. Will there be any noticable performance benefit of using option 2?

Comment: @ClickUpvote: I doubt it. The main benefit you get from using a `DocumentFragment` is in preventing unnecessary browser reflows/repaints when adding multiple consecutive elements to the DOM. Assembling the contents of the fragment is therefore likely to take a small proportion of the overall time, so possible performance benefits in that part are likely to be small.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: You'll need to clone the buffer every time before adding it to the document, by the way.